# Изменение маршрута по клику

Tags: javascript, jquery, яндекс-карты

Можно ли как-то исправить код, что бы при клике на ссылку менялся маршрут. Т.е. во второе значение маршрута `"Новый город"` подставлялось значение из `data-map` (`pos`) и происходило изменение маршрута?

Если помещаю onclick внутрь `init()` карта не инициализируется до клика.

```js
$('.map__link').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    var pos = $(this).data('map');
 });   


$('.map__link').on('click', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();

  var pos = $(this).data('map');

  return pos;
});  


function init () {  

   
    // Объявляем набор опорных точек, и массив индексов транзитных точек.
    var referencePoints = [
            "Россия, Москва",
            "Новый город"
        ];

    // Создаем мультимаршрут и настраиваем его внешний вид с помощью опций.
    var multiRoute = new ymaps.multiRouter.MultiRoute({
        referencePoints: referencePoints
    }, {
        // Внешний вид путевых точек.
        wayPointStartIconColor: "#000000",
        // Задаем собственную картинку для последней путевой точки.
        // wayPointFinishIconLayout: "default#image",
        // wayPointFinishIconImageHref: "images/sokolniki.png",
        wayPointFinishIconLayout: 'islands#icon',
        iconColor: '#0095b6',
        wayPointFinishIconImageSize: [30, 30],
        wayPointFinishIconImageOffset: [-15, -15],
        // Позволяет скрыть иконки путевых точек маршрута.
        // wayPointVisible:false,

        // Внешний вид транзитных точек.
        viaPointIconRadius: 7,
        viaPointIconFillColor: "#000088",
        viaPointActiveIconFillColor: "#fc6059",
        // Транзитные точки можно перетаскивать, при этом
        // маршрут будет перестраиваться.
        viaPointDraggable: true,
        // Позволяет скрыть иконки транзитных точек маршрута.
        // viaPointVisible:false,

        // Внешний вид точечных маркеров под путевыми точками.
        pinIconFillColor: "#000088",
        pinActiveIconFillColor: "#fc6059",
        // Позволяет скрыть точечные маркеры путевых точек.
        // pinVisible:false,
        
        // Внешний вид линии маршрута.
        routeStrokeWidth: 2,
        routeStrokeColor: "#000088",
        routeActiveStrokeWidth: 6,
        routeActiveStrokeColor: "#fc6059",
        // Автоматически устанавливать границы карты так, чтобы маршрут был виден целиком.
        boundsAutoApply: true
    });

        
    
    // Настраиваем внешний вид второй точки через прямой доступ к ней.
    customizeSecondPoint();

    // Создаем кнопку.
    // var removePointsButton = new ymaps.control.Button({
    //     data: { content: "Удалить промежуточные точки"},
    //     options: { selectOnClick: true }
    // });

    // Объявляем обработчики для кнопки.
    // removePointsButton.events.add('select', function () {
    //     multiRoute.model.setReferencePoints([
    //         referencePoints[0],
    //         referencePoints[referencePoints.length - 1]
    //     ], []);
    // });

    // removePointsButton.events.add('deselect', function () {
    //     multiRoute.model.setReferencePoints(referencePoints, viaIndexes);
    //     // Т.к. вторая точка была удалена, нужно заново ее настроить.
    //     customizeSecondPoint();
    // });

    // Функция настройки внешнего вида второй точки.
    function customizeSecondPoint () {
        
        multiRoute.model.events.once("requestsuccess", function () {
            var yandexWayPoint = multiRoute.getWayPoints().get(1);
            // Создаем балун у метки второй точки.
            ymaps.geoObject.addon.balloon.get(yandexWayPoint);
            yandexWayPoint.options.set({
                preset: "islands#icon",
                // iconContentLayout: ymaps.templateLayoutFactory.createClass(
                //     '<span style="color: red;">Я</span>ндекс'
                // ),
                // balloonContentLayout: ymaps.templateLayoutFactory.createClass(
                //     '{{ properties.address|raw }}'
                // )
            });
        });
    }



    // Создаем карту с добавленной на нее кнопкой.
    var myMap = new ymaps.Map('map', {
        center: [55.739625, 37.54120],
        zoom: 7,
        // controls: [removePointsButton]
    }, {
        buttonMaxWidth: 300
    });

    // Добавляем мультимаршрут на карту.
    myMap.geoObjects.add(multiRoute);

        
}

ymaps.ready(init);
```

```css
#map {
  height: 400px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="http://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1/?lang=ru_RU" type="text/javascript"></script>


<div id="map"></div>

<a href="#" data-map="Москва" class="map__link active">
  Схема 1
</a>
<a href="#" data-map="Киев" class="map__link">
  Схема 2
</a>
<a href="#" data-map="Воронеж" class="map__link">
  Схема 3
</a>
```

Comment: Метка "инспекция кода" это code-review а не "как решить проблему". То есть "смотрите у меня есть работающий код, что в  нем не так"? Поэтому наверное она тут не нужна.

Comment: показываться должен только один маршрут или все три, но один - активный?

Comment: @Grundy, один активный, по клику на соответствующую кнопку

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Маршрут строится сразу, поэтому вместо подмены значения "Новый город", на то, что указано в дата-атрибуте, просто строится маршрут до наиболее подходящего места.

Вместо этого можно перенести объявление обработчиков внутрь функции `init` и уже внутри обработчиков создавать маршруты и добавлять/удалять их с карты.

Также для первого запуска можно сразу брать значение с активного элемента.

Сам обработчик может выглядеть следующий образом:

1. если элемент уже активен - ничего не делать.
2. удалить класс `active` с текущего активного элемента.
3. добавить класс `active` элементу по которому кликнули.
4. удалить с карты добавленный маршрут.
5. добавить на карту новый маршрут основанный на data-атрибуте.

Пример:

```js
function createRoute(points) {

    var route = new ymaps.multiRouter.MultiRoute({
      referencePoints: points
    }, {
      wayPointStartIconColor: "#000000",
      wayPointFinishIconLayout: 'islands#icon',
      iconColor: '#0095b6',
      wayPointFinishIconImageSize: [30, 30],
      wayPointFinishIconImageOffset: [-15, -15],
      viaPointIconRadius: 7,
      viaPointIconFillColor: "#000088",
      viaPointActiveIconFillColor: "#fc6059",
      viaPointDraggable: true,
      pinIconFillColor: "#000088",
      pinActiveIconFillColor: "#fc6059",
      routeStrokeWidth: 2,
      routeStrokeColor: "#000088",
      routeActiveStrokeWidth: 6,
      routeActiveStrokeColor: "#fc6059",
      boundsAutoApply: true
    });
    customizeSecondPoint(route);
    return route;
  }
  // Функция настройки внешнего вида второй точки.

function customizeSecondPoint(multiRoute) {

  multiRoute.model.events.once("requestsuccess", function() {
    var yandexWayPoint = multiRoute.getWayPoints().get(1);
    // Создаем балун у метки второй точки.
    ymaps.geoObject.addon.balloon.get(yandexWayPoint);
    yandexWayPoint.options.set({
      preset: "islands#icon"
    });
  });
}

function init() {
  // Создаем карту с добавленной на нее кнопкой.
  myMap = new ymaps.Map('map', {
    center: [55.739625, 37.54120],
    zoom: 7,
  }, {
    buttonMaxWidth: 300
  });
  var activeRoute = createRoute(["Россия, Москва", $('.map__link.active').data('map')]);
  myMap.geoObjects.add(activeRoute)

  $('.map__link').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if ($(this).hasClass('active')) return;
    $('.active').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');

    // удаляем добавленные объекты
    myMap.geoObjects.removeAll();

    var activeRoute = createRoute(["Россия, Москва", $(this).data('map')]);
    myMap.geoObjects.add(activeRoute)

  });
}
ymaps.ready(init);
```

```css
#map {
  height: 400px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1/?lang=ru_RU" type="text/javascript"></script>


<div id="map"></div>

<a href="#" data-map="Минск" class="map__link active">
  Схема 1
</a>
<a href="#" data-map="Киев" class="map__link">
  Схема 2
</a>
<a href="#" data-map="Воронеж" class="map__link">
  Схема 3
</a>
```

В примере выше, маршруты каждый раз создаются по клику, вместо этого их можно создать один раз и просто выбирать нужный.

Кроме того, не получилось использовать [метод `remove`](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/ref/reference/IGeoObjectCollection-docpage/#remove) для удаления текущего маршрута, поэтому вместо него используется [`removeAll`](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/ref/reference/IGeoObjectCollection-docpage/#removeAll) - который удаляет *все* объекты.

В текущем примере разницы нет, не она наверняка будет, если на карту будет добавлено еще что-то кроме одно маршрута.

Answer (score 1):

Мое решение на тот момент:

```js
function init () {
    
    // Точки маршрута для примера
    var 
        pointA = "Россия, Москва, Ащеулов переулок, д 9",
        pointB = "коттеджный поселок Лесные Озёра, Россия, Московская область, Чеховский район",
        pointC = 'Россия, Воронеж ',
        pointD = 'Россия, Щелковское шоссе '
            /**
             * Создаем мультимаршрут.
             * @see https://api.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/ref/reference/multiRouter.MultiRoute.xml
             */
            multiRoute = new ymaps.multiRouter.MultiRoute({
                referencePoints: [
                    pointA,
                    pointB
                ],
                params: {
                    // Ограничение на максимальное количество маршрутов, возвращаемое маршрутизатором.
                    results: 4
                }
            }, {
                // Автоматически устанавливать границы карты так, чтобы маршрут был виден целиком.
                boundsAutoApply: true,
                viaPointIconRadius: 7,
                viaPointIconFillColor: "#000088",
                viaPointActiveIconFillColor: "#E63E92",
                // Транзитные точки можно перетаскивать, при этом
                // маршрут будет перестраиваться.
                viaPointDraggable: true,
                // Внешний вид точечных маркеров под путевыми точками.
                pinIconFillColor: "#000088",
                pinActiveIconFillColor: "#E63E92",
                // Позволяет скрыть точечные маркеры путевых точек.
                // pinVisible:false,
                
                // Внешний вид линии маршрута.
                routeStrokeWidth: 2,
                routeStrokeColor: "#000088",
                routeActiveStrokeWidth: 6,
                routeActiveStrokeColor: "#E63E92",
                // Автоматически устанавливать границы карты так, чтобы маршрут был виден целиком.
                boundsAutoApply: true
            });

        // Создаем кнопку.
        var changePointsButton3 = new ymaps.control.Button({
            data: {content: " "},
            options: {
                selectOnClick: true,

                layout: ymaps.templateLayoutFactory.createClass(
                    // Если кнопка не нажата, к ней применится css-стиль 'myButton'
                    // Если кнопка нажата, к ней применятся css-стили 'myButton' и 'myButtonSelected'.
                    "<div class='my-YButton my-YButton-3 {% if state.selected %}myButtonSelected{% endif %}' title='{{ data.title }}'>" +
                    "{{ data.content }} Маршрут <span>" +  
                    "№ 1</span></div>"
                )
            }
        });

        var changePointsButton1 = new ymaps.control.Button({
            data: {content: " "},
            options: {
                selectOnClick: true,

                layout: ymaps.templateLayoutFactory.createClass(
                    // Если кнопка не нажата, к ней применится css-стиль 'myButton'
                    // Если кнопка нажата, к ней применятся css-стили 'myButton' и 'myButtonSelected'.
                    "<div class='my-YButton my-YButton-1 {% if state.selected %}myButtonSelected{% endif %}' title='{{ data.title }}'>" +
                    "{{ data.content }} Маршрут <span>" +  
                    "№ 2</span></div>"
                )
            }
        });

        var changePointsButton2 = new ymaps.control.Button({
            data: {content: " "},
            options: {
                selectOnClick: true,

                layout: ymaps.templateLayoutFactory.createClass(
                    // Если кнопка не нажата, к ней применится css-стиль 'myButton'
                    // Если кнопка нажата, к ней применятся css-стили 'myButton' и 'myButtonSelected'.
                    "<div class='my-YButton my-YButton-2 {% if state.selected %}myButtonSelected{% endif %}' title='{{ data.title }}'>" +
                    "{{ data.content }} Маршрут <span>" +  
                    "№ 3</span></div>"
                )
            }
        });

        // Объявляем обработчики для кнопки.

        // Первая кнопка карты
        changePointsButton1.events.add('select', function () {
            multiRoute.model.setReferencePoints([pointA, pointB]);
        });

        changePointsButton1.events.add('deselect', function () {
            multiRoute.model.setReferencePoints([pointA, pointB]);
        });

        // Вторая кнопка карты
        changePointsButton2.events.add('select', function () {
            var referencePoints = multiRoute.model.getReferencePoints();
                referencePoints.splice(1, 0, 'Россия, Щелковское шоссе ');
                /**
                 * Добавляем транзитную точку в модель мультимаршрута.
                 * Обратите внимание, что транзитные точки могут находится только
                 * между двумя путевыми точками, т.е. не могут быть крайними точками маршрута.
                 * @see https://api.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/ref/reference/multiRouter.MultiRouteModel.xml#setReferencePoints
                 */
                multiRoute.model.setReferencePoints(referencePoints, [1]);
            
        });

        changePointsButton2.events.add('deselect', function () {
            var referencePoints = multiRoute.model.getReferencePoints();
                    referencePoints.splice(1, 1);
                    multiRoute.model.setReferencePoints(referencePoints, []);
        });

        changePointsButton3.events.add('select', function () {
            multiRoute.model.setReferencePoints([pointA, pointC]);
        });

        changePointsButton3.events.add('deselect', function () {
            multiRoute.model.setReferencePoints([pointA, pointB]);
        });

    // Создаем карту с добавленными на нее кнопками.
    var myMap = new ymaps.Map('map', {
        center: [55.750625, 37.626],
        zoom: 7,
        controls: [changePointsButton1, changePointsButton2, changePointsButton3]
    }, {
        buttonMaxWidth: 300
    });

    // Добавляем мультимаршрут на карту.
    myMap.geoObjects.add(multiRoute);
}

ymaps.ready(init);
```

```css
#map {
    height: 498px;
    width: 100%;
}

.my-YButton {
    font-size: 1.375rem;
    line-height: 1.5rem;
    color: #0f3223;
    display: block;
    text-align: center !important;
    background: rgba(255,255,255,.8);
    width: 295px;
    border:  1px solid transparent;
    border-radius: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    padding: 7px 0;
    position: relative;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.my-YButton {
    position: absolute;
    left: 100px;
    z-index: 9999;
}

.my-YButton-1 {
    top: 75px;
}

.my-YButton-2 {
    top: 159px;
}

.my-YButton-3 {
    top: 243px;
}

.my-YButton.myButtonSelected  {
    border: 1px solid #0f3223;
}


.my-YButton span {
    font-weight: bold;
    display: block;
    text-align: center !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1/?lang=ru_RU"></script>


<div id="map"></div>
```

Минусы: трудно стилизовать, переключение маршрутов работает примерно как чекбокс, ...

Answer (score 0):

В документации и примерах неоднократно упоминается эта функция.. Читайте пожалуйста документацию

`multiRoute.model.setReferencePoints([point1, point2]));`

Код изменяет точки на указанные внутри массива. 
Чтобы редактировать точки мышкой, то есть методы:

`multiRoute.editor.start();` и `multiRoute.editor.stop();`

Первый разрешает перетаскивание точек по карте мышкой, а второй метод закрывает режим редактирования. По кнопке, например.

Comment: Добавь описание что это за код, что он делает, почему его надо использовать. Желательно добавить пример использования на основе кода из вопроса.

Comment: А также посмотри соседний ответ автора вопроса :)

Comment: @Grundy хотя я слился( Но мне яро непонятно, что за творение висит в правильном ответе..

Comment: @Grundy и почему на правильном ответе минуc, а на ответе, который ни в коем случае нельзя применять при возможностях api, висит 1 плюс

Comment: Принятый ответ - удобен и работает везде, а главное был дан своевременно! Ваш ответ трудно назвать вообще ответом, какие-то реплики подсказки и не более, не видно работающего кода. Дайте полноценный ответ и Вы получите плюс, а то и гораздо больше! =) P.S: минус не от меня!

Comment: @HamSter нельзя давать делать за человека всю его работу. Я дал ответ "как изменить координаты точки". Я дал функцию, которая в одну строку меняет эти точки. Как и функцию, которая позволяет прямо на карте менять визуально точки. Документацию по этим функциям (которая в открытом доступе!) я уже искать не намерен, вопрос не об этом

Comment: честно говоря ваш ответ мне совершенно непонятен, ну да спасибо за старания, возможно кому-то он больше поможет!